# Compiling OpenFOAM's scotch on macOS

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile, clang, gnu-make

I am trying to compile the `scotch` library embedded into the OpenFOAM.org third-party repository [here](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-dev/tree/master/scotch_6.0.9). I ran the command

```
make -C ./ThirdParty-dev/scotch_6.0.9/src/
```

and I get the below error message:

```
(cd libscotch ;      make VERSION=6 RELEASE=0 PATCHLEVEL=9 scotch && make install)
make                    \
                    CC="gcc"                    \
                    CCD="gcc"                   \
                    scotch.h                    \
                    scotchf.h                   \
                    libscotch.so                    \
                    libscotcherr.so             \
                    libscotcherrexit.so
gcc  -O3 -DCOMMON_FILE_COMPRESS_GZ -DCOMMON_RANDOM_FIXED_SEED -DSCOTCH_RENAME -Drestrict=__restrict -DSCOTCH_VERSION_NUM=6 -DSCOTCH_RELEASE_NUM=0 -DSCOTCH_PATCHLEVEL_NUM=9 dummysizes.c -o dummysizes -Xlinker --no-as-needed  -lz -lm -lrt
ld: unknown option: --no-as-needed
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [dummysizes] Error 1
make[1]: *** [scotch] Error 2
make: *** [libscotch] Error 2
```

I am not sure what this error message means. If it is complaining about `scotch` not being available, that's why I'm compiling it in the first place. Out of desperation, I also tried to install it via `brew install scotch` to no avail. I would appreciate it if you could help me understand the above error message and resolve the issue.

Comment: The `gcc  -O3 ... -Xlinker --no-as-needed  ...` command is passing the `--no-as-needed` option to the linker `ld`.  Unfortunately `ld` on MacOS doesn't recognize that option.  The best way to change that depends on exactly how you configured things.  You might have to edit the correct `makefile` (having first made a suitable backup of course).

Comment: @G.M. what is the cross-platform alternative to `ld`? Or maybe I can install it on macOS via HomeBrew? 

Answer (score 1):

The scotch build is a bit different in that they manage all of the OS/compiler-specific bits separately via a `src/Makefile.inc` that the user is responsible for providing. Of course they also provide a number of examples in the src/Make.inc/ directory, but they may not properly cover your particular OS/compiler requirements.

Since you grabbed the scotch source files from a third-party source instead of from the pristine upstream sources, you also have someone else's `src/Makefile.inc` that happens to be a Linux-specific version. So no surprise that it has incorrect link (or even compile) options.

The Darwin-specific makefile adjustments that are used by openfoam.com:

```
# Linux:
LIB         = .so
ARFLAGS     = $(WM_CFLAGS) -shared -o
LDFLAGS     = -Xlinker --no-as-needed $(WM_LDFLAGS) -lm -lrt

# Darwin:
LIB         = .dylib
ARFLAGS     = $(WM_CFLAGS) -dynamiclib -undefined dynamic_lookup -o
LDFLAGS     = $(WM_LDFLAGS) -lm
```

Without worrying about any other source of differences (in the OpenFOAM `WM_CFLAGS` and `WM_LDFLAGS` variables), it would appear that you are using Linux (gcc only?) link options for Darwin - so should be no surprise that they don't work.

Comment: Thanks, Mark for the elaborated response. You can remove the other answer. I will try your instructions, but two questions for now: 1. What do you mean by a Third Part source?  I downloaded from the official repository on GitHub. 2. With the link you provided earlier it appeared as if you are incorporating some macOS patches upstream. Is that right? If that is correct, is it appreciated if I open macOS-specific questions (bugs, feature requests) on your GitLab/GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

The location for the pristine scotch sources move around a bit (seems to be related to their filer) but a reasonably uptodate reference is always included in the [OpenFOAM ThirdParty BUILD.md](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/ThirdParty-common/-/blob/develop/BUILD.md). The URLs are provided as links, but also listed near the bottom of the file for easy grepping.
The current scotch link : https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/file/38352/scotch_6.1.0.tar.gz

The newest scotch is actually scotch-6.1.2 but there appears to be a regression in the dgraph calculation (the distributed graph in ptscotch) so probably better to stick with 6.1.0 for now.
Here is the information for the scotch repo itself (https://gitlab.inria.fr/scotch/scotch) - should be the most reliable source of information.